# Monitoring IIS with SNMP

Tags: windows, iis, snmp, wmi

I'm trying to monitor IIS using the Windows integrated SNMP service (for versions 2000, 2003 ans 2008 of Windows Server, but i'm doing my experiments on a 2008 R2 box). So far I was able to install the SNMP service, and query mib-2 values without problems.

Now, I'm having trouble to monitor IIS informations, as the SNMP service does not seem to know about the `.iso.org.dod.internet.private.enterprises.microsoft.software.internetServer` OIDs. Walking the entire SNMP tree only gets the mib-2 stuff as well as the names of some services, but that's it.

I did't find anything interesting in the service configuration panel.

So how do I configure this service to get IIS information, or other WMI data for that matter (I installed the SNMP WMI Provider) ? I can't find any documentation about that !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SNMP provider for WMI does the exact opposite of what I think you're expecting it to do.  The SNMP provider allows SNMP information to be accessed via WMI.  I'm not sure about 2008 but in older versions of windows you needed to have snmp installed before you added IIS.  I would suspect its the same with 2008.  Try removing the web server role and re-adding it. (presuming that's the correct OID- I can't seem to find any docs on that OID), but you should see something when you walk the tree

Comment: Yeah, uninstalling and reinstalling did the trick, thanks !